# How can I extend Gson to constructor and generate a default object for any type?

Tags: java, json, reflection, gson

All ,

Gson inspire me a lot , Now I what to extend Gson to builder any other type of object with some custom default value . I should rewrite Gson's which part ? I really want to reuse the Gson reflect and supported basic types . But I find there are some difficult to do that base on current Gson 's designing after review its source code .

Now my requirements can represent as below :

I define a POJO class , such as :

**TestInputParam.class:**

```
public class TestInputParam{
    private Date startTime;
    private String name;
    private int num;

    //setters and gettters
}
```

**Requirements :**

```
GsonEx<TestInputParam> gsonEx = new GsonEx<TestInputParam>();
TestInputParam defaultParam = gsonEx.build(TestInputParam.class) 

System.out.println(new Gson().toJson(defaultParam));
```

**Result:**

```
It should output this object default value .
```

**Notes:**

My understanding is : new Gson().fromJson(stringContent , type) build its corresponding Object with StringContent value by JsonReader , Just extend it can build its corresponding object by some Default or random value . don't let its field value from stringContent .

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand. Are you asking to return an object with default values if JSON string is empty?

Comment: No, I mean How to extend Gson to as a Object builder base on its type . That means auto fill a type of object as some values as we custom by a value factory . or some random values .

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question, you may be looking for Gson's type adapters. These allow you to create [custom serialization and deserialization](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Custom-Serialization-and-Deserialization).

Let's say you have the following JSON:

```
{
  "foo": ...,
  "bar": ...,

  "testInputParam": {
    "startTime": {...},
    "name": "SomeName",
    "num": 1
  },

  "someArray": [...]    
}
```

For example, you can write a custom deserializer like this:

```
private class TestInputParamDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<TestInputParam> {

  public TestInputParam deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context)
      throws JsonParseException {

    //This is the actual "testInputParam" JSON object...
    JsonObject object = json.getAsJsonObject();

    //This is the custom object you will return...
    TestInputParam result = new TestInputParam();

    //Fill in the "startDate" field with the current Date instead of the actual value in the JSON...
    result.setStartDate = new Date(); 

    //Use the actual "name" found in the JSON...
    result.name = object.get("name").getAsJsonString();

    //Fill in the "num" with a random value...
    result.setNum = new Random().nextInt();

    //Finally return your custom object...
    return result;
  }
}
```

Once you have written your custom deserializer you just have to add it to the Gson object with:

```
GsonBuilder gson = new GsonBuilder();
gson.registerTypeAdapter(TestInputParam.class, new TestInputParamDeserializer());
```

Now, whenever you use this `gson` object to deserialize your JSON string, each time it finds a JSON object representing a `TestInputParam` class, it will use the custom deserialization, but you can still use default deserialization for the rest of the JSON string...

---

EDIT: With this approach you have to write a custom serializer/deserializer for each class you want to have custom serialization/deserialization. There is also a class called `TypeAdapterFactory` that allows you to create type adapters for set of related types. You can find info and examples [on Gson API documentation](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/TypeAdapterFactory.html).

Comment: Yes , You catch my ideas , but your solution means for each TestInputParam , we need to write them one by one ?

Comment: What I want to implement is for a common solution by Generic type . it just like a Object Factory , it can create any object with its basic fields have some random values or custom value . not just for special POJO , such as : TestInputParam